# R does not find "update.packages"

Tags: r, package, updates

I am running `R` in version `3.4.1` under Windows 7 64-bit. When I give `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` the routine starts, identifies some packages to be updated, downloads packages, and then returns:

```
Error in update.packages(ask = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "update.packages"
Execution halted
```

I cannot find a reason for this problem. I just installed the newest version of `R`.

---

**Complete output:** I add the complete output. Maybe the problem is hidden in here, see e.g. the `Warning messages`. I shortened some paths (`...`). The problem seems to be with package `knitr`?

```
  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
knitr   1.16   1.17             FALSE
rlang  0.1.1  0.1.2              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 466606 bytes (455 KB)
downloaded 455 KB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\...
installing the source package ‘knitr’

trying URL 'https://cran.wu.ac.at/src/contrib/knitr_1.17.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 769923 bytes (751 KB)
downloaded 751 KB

Error in update.packages(ask = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "update.packages"
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\...’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "N:\RLibrary" C:\Users\...' had status 1 
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Does running `utils::update.packages(ask = FALSE)` change anything?

Comment: @Aurèle no, same problem

Comment: @Aurèle can it be that the problem is with package `knitr`?

Comment: Did you update R version recently? Related: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Install-R-2-10-1-on-Windows-XP-Errors-td1310942.html